# Use initWithObjects on data from Array of Objects

Tags: xcode, arrays, uipickerview

Lets say I have a number of objects:

```
@interface City : NSObject {
    NSString  *name;
    NSString  *country;
    int       yearFirstTimeVisited;
}
```

Which are stored in an Array of objects:

```
city = [[City alloc] initWithName:@"London":@"UK",2002];
[pickerValues addObject:city];
city = [[City alloc] initWithName:@"Paris":@"France",2003];
[pickerValues addObject:city];
city = [[City alloc] initWithName:@"LA":@"USA",2003];
[pickerValues addObject:city];
```

Now I want to load the cities in to a picker-wheel. Naturally I can do this manually:

```
pickerValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"London",@"Paris", @"LA",nil];
```

But this is results in 2 sets of data I have to maintain in the code. I'm sure that there is a better option. I have searched the web, but could not find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a new array for the picker.

```
NSMutableArray *pickerNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[pickerValues count]];
for(City *city in pickerValues){
    [pickerNames addObject:[city name]];
}
```

It's also a best practice to prefix your custom classes like `VCCity` instead of just `City`. I picked `VC` from your username but it's common to pick letters from the project name.

Comment: Btw: the arrayWithCount shall be arrayWithCapacity.

Answer (score 3):

Even better, use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i).  `-[NSArray valueForKey:]` will do the loop for you.

```
NSArray* pickerNames = [pickerValues valueForKey:@"name"];
```